# How to draw scatter plot of np.array?

Tags: python

Assume I have the following array:

```
X = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3], [8, 7], [8, 8], [25, 80]])
```

How can I make scatter plot (`matplotlib`) of `X` ?

scatter require 2 parameters (x, y)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


X = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3], [8, 7], [8, 8], [25, 80]])

plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(*zip(*X))
plt.show()
```